# Query to find the list of salesmen who had sales more than average sales for each year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (link of the table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11P_ElrtCXwE3NYAoP-auO7w-Et_zd6omn-v-zMdu8KA/edit?usp=sharing) from which I have to find the list of salesmen who had sales more than average sales for each year.

I have written a query below but it isn't working.

```
SELECT t1.salesman, t1.AVG(sale), t1.year
SUM(CASE WHEN t1.AVG(sale)>t2.AVG(sale) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0
FROM Sales_temp as t1
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT t2.year, t2.AVG(sale)
 FROM Sales_temp as t2
 Group by t2.year)
ON t1.year = t2.year
Group by t1.salesman
```

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Linking to a Google sheet is not an acceptable source of sample data.  Please include all data directly in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity's sake, if you are using MySQL version 8 or later, then we can use analytic functions here:

```
SELECT year, salesman, sale
FROM Sales_temp
WHERE sale > AVG(sale) OVER (PARTITION BY year);
```

Comment: I'm using google cloud and error message says that 'analytic function not allowed in where clause'.

Comment: Rajan I clearly said this was a MySQL 8+ solution.  Look at the answer by @cars if you need a pre 8+ solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT salesman, sale, year
FROM Sales_temp
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT year ayear, AVG(sale) asale
    FROM Sales_temp
    GROUP BY year
) atbl
    ON year = ayear AND sale > asale
ORDER BY year, salesman;
```

By giving your subquery columns alias names you can do without the alias names for the tables. This simplifies things a little. I changed your `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`, as this will restrict your output to those records that *can* be joined, i. e. have `sale>asale`.

I also added the `ORDER BY` clause to improve the readability of the result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT a.salesman, a.sale, a.year
FROM Sales_temp a
where a.sale > ( SELECT avg(b.sale) 
                 FROM Sales_temp b
                 where b.year = a.year
                group by b.year
               )
```

Comment: This will list all salesmen with sales greater than the **overall average** (a single value), taken over all records in the table, i. e. looking at *all years*.

Comment: Your edited subquery will now return several values (one for each year). This will cause the overall statement to fail, because the comparison with value `a.sale > ...` expects a *single* (scalar) value.